# Public Digital Signature Validation with JWE

Tags: encryption, web-application, digital-signature, jwt, node.js

After reading [JSON Web Encryption (JWE)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516) and making a Node JS [JWE POC](https://github.com/psenger/jwe_example) demonstrating key mode using *Key Encryption*. I'm a bit confused as to how to validate that the sender of the message was in fact, the actual sender (not a man-in-the-middle with access to the public key).

With PGP, public keys are exchanged, and the message is validated against the [digital signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature). Is it possible to do the same with the JWS and JWE specs? I had a feeling this would somehow be done in the ADD, but doesn't appear to be the case as this is computing the AAD for the purpose of the Auth Tag. Obviously the Public Keys would have to be exchanged for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

With JWS you can use one of the signature schemed supported. Broadly there are three options - HS, RS and PS - HMAC , RSA PKCS 1.5 and RSA PSS respectively.

The payload and protected headers would be signed and the signature would be transmitted. As far as overall security is concerned, be aware of alg:None issues with JWS libraries and the possibility kg replay attacks if exp header isn't included.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I would just like to be clear, you are suggesting we wrap the JWE with a JWS. E.g.

```
JWS: [
 JWE: [ Message ] <- encrypted with the Public Key of the Receiver
] <- Signed with the Private Key of the Sender 
```

I understand the security risk you raised regarding the attribute ``alg`` set to ``none`` in the JWS-JOSE. Is there a issue with using ``RSA-SHA256`` as I have done In my [example](https://github.com/psenger/jwe_example)? I can then exchange Public Keys between the two and no need for the cost of a X.509.

Comment: 1. Yes you are right about the suggestion.

Comment: 2. alg: None is an issue when the recipient accepts alg: None. The recipient should use libraries which does not fall back to alg:None.